# What's the equivalent of ELSEIF in Apache hive?

Tags: hive

I'm looking for a conditional structure in Apache Hive like the following Java code:

```
if (condition) value
elseif (condition) value
...
else value
```

Is there a way to do this in HiveQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the case statement in HIVE

**CASE Statement**

The syntax for the case statement is:

```
CASE   [ expression ]
       WHEN condition1 THEN result1
       WHEN condition2 THEN result2
       ...
       WHEN conditionn THEN resultn
       ELSE result
END
```

Here expression is optional. It is the value that you are comparing to the list of conditions. (ie: condition1, condition2, ... conditionn).

All the conditions must be of same datatype. Conditions are evaluated in the order listed. Once a condition is found to be true, the case statement will return the result and not evaluate the conditions any further.

All the results must be of same datatype. This is the value returned once a condition is found to be true.

IF no condition is found to be true, then the case statement will return the value in the ELSE clause. If the ELSE clause is omitted and no condition is found to be true, then the case statement will return NULL

Example:

```
CASE   Fruit
       WHEN 'APPLE' THEN 'The owner is APPLE'
       WHEN 'ORANGE' THEN 'The owner is ORANGE'
       ELSE 'It is another Fruit'
END
```

The other form of CASE is

```
CASE
       WHEN Fruit = 'APPLE' THEN 'The owner is APPLE'
       WHEN Fruit = 'ORANGE' THEN 'The owner is ORANGE'
       ELSE 'It is another Fruit'

END
```